# Reading/writing PLC tags from PLC s7-1500

Tags: c#, plc

I was wondering if there is any way to read and write values from the PLC tags folder using a custom c# application?

[image]

I have tried using **Snap7** which is great tool to use and actually got it working, but only reading and writing data blocks and not tags what I am willing to achieve. I haven't tried **Libnodave** just yet.

Would you please recommend me a way to achieve this and if there is other ways to do this.

**Update #1**

I partiely understand now how to read and write Merkers. But how about Inputs and outputs such as those?

[image]

**Update #2**

I have setup a watch table and got it working using Python Snap7, but wasn't able to do the same using C#. 
[image]

Comment: Tags are an OPC concept.  That costs money, you'll have to go shopping by yourself..

Comment: @HansPassant Hi! Thanks. Would you please explain little bit more about what you really mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides any tag value from a datablock, libnodave can get/set input, output and memory tags. Snap7 can also do that. I do not see any problem with that.

Answer (score 2):

Its very easy to read and write using [Libnodave](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libnodave). Download latest `Libnodave.dll`  from official site and refer [this](https://alexsentcha.wordpress.com/libnodave-exchange-data-with-siemens-plc-2/vb-net-exchange-data-with-siemens-plc/) sample. You will get an idea.

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a try and come back with an answer!

Comment: Do you have any example or test files I can have a look at?

Comment: that link is already having the sample code.. did u try that?